# Bound and free variables in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$\forall x: (x > 5) \rightarrow \exists y: (y + 3) = z + x$$

Which of the following statements is false?

Select one:

1. The variables x and y are bound.
2. The statement is true for any natural z.
3. The statement is a proposition.
4. Every variable in the statement is either free or bound.

I was told the answer is **4**.

But I thought that z would be free making **4** true.

I am looking for a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In fully "symbolized" form :

> $\forall x (x > 5) \to \exists y  (y + 3) = z + x$

Thus we have : the third occurrence of $x$ is *free*, $y$ is *bound* and $z$ is free.

If so, 4) is not true, because $x$ has both free and bound occurrences.

If we supply a "missing" pair of parentheses :

> $\forall x [(x > 5) \to \exists y  (y + 3) = z + x]$

now we have : $x$ and $y$ *bound*, while $z$ free. In this case, both options 1) and 4) are true.

Comment: the answer ended up being c.

Comment: A variable is free in a formula if it has at least one free occurrence.